# theano T.grad() error: not part of computational graph

Tags: python, theano, hessian-matrix

code:

```
a = T.vector()
b = T.vector()

loss = T.sum(a-b)

dy = T.grad(loss, a)
d2y = T.grad(loss, dy)

f = theano.function([a,b], y)
print f([.5,.5,.5], [1,0,1])
```

output:

```
theano.gradient.DisconnectedInputError: grad method was asked to compute
the gradientwith respect to a variable that is not part of the
computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a non-differentiable
operator: Elemwise{second}.0
```

how is a derivative of the graph not part of the graph? Is this why scan is used to compute the hessian?

Comment: Presumably you mean `f = theano.function([a,b], dy)` - you haven't defined `y` above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
d2y = T.grad(loss, dy)
```

you are attempting to compute the gradient of the loss with respect to `dy`. However the loss depends only on the values of `a` and `b` and not `dy`, hence the error. It only makes sense to compute partial derivatives of the loss with respect to parameters that actually affect its value.

The easiest way to compute the Hessian in Theano is to use the [`theano.gradient.hessian`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/gradient.html#theano.gradient.hessian) convenience function:

```
d2y = theano.gradient.hessian(loss, a)
```

See the documentation [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/gradients.html#computing-the-hessian) for an alternative manual method that uses  a combination of `theano.grad` and `theano.scan`.

In your example the Hessian will be a 3x3 matrix of zeros, since the partial derivative of the loss w.r.t. `a` is independent of `a` (it's just a vector of ones).

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand why "he partial derivative of the `loss` w.r.t. `a` is independent of `a`"

Comment: The gradient of the loss w.r.t. `a` is just a vector of ones, so all of the second order partial derivatives w.r.t. `a` will be zero. For example, if *a* was scalar then *d/da (a - b) = 1* and *d^2/da^2 (a - b) = 0*.